# How to attach Dropzone.js uploads to a form element

Tags: 7, forms, javascript, files

I'm integrating dropzone.js into my form, but I have an issue regarding my file uploads.  I have my dropzone set up, and file uploads are in the $_FILES array.  I want to call [file_save_upload](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7) to handle the file management, but per the code:

```
// Make sure there's an upload to process.
if (empty($_FILES['files']['name'][$form_field_name])) {
    return NULL;
}
```

it looks for the files under $_FILES['files']['name'].  The dropzone.js uploads my files to $_FILES['file']['file'].

I haven't seen an easy way to specify an input element for dropzone.js to upload to.  On the Form API side, I could just mimic the functionality of file_save_upload(), but all the code already exists and it does a lot, and I'd hate to duplicate it.

Maybe I can copy the $_FILES['file']['file'] array over to $_FILES['files'], then call file_save_upload()?  I'm trying to make sure there is a better way to do it before I start hacking.

Comment: You can try to borrow some code from https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads or https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_upload

Comment: It doesn't work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have the files under $_FILES['files'].

My JS code:

```
(function ($) {

    Drupal.behaviors.dz = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            Dropzone.options.picsForm = {
                paramName: "files",
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                maxFiles: 100,

                init: function() {
                    var dz = this;
                    // #edit-next is the id of my submit button
                    this.element.querySelector("#edit-next").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        dz.processQueue();
                    });

                }
            };

        }
      }

})(jQuery);
```

The '$form_field_name' parameter is a numeric index now, so I just get the count of the $_FILES['names'] array and call file_save_upload() for each one.

Comment: Is it possible that you share your final implementation?